# String concatenation in java is not working on one system

Tags: java, eclipse, string, war, concatenation

I believe that most of you would be thinking that this is the same question you have heard multiple times (and answered ) about string concatenation in Java. But trust me, it is different. In fact, so different that I am even hesitant in posting it here. But anyways, here it is. I have some piece of code which goes like:

```
public void handleSuccess(String result) 
{
       result = result.trim();
       MessageBox.alert("Information","Result after trimming: '" + result + "'");
       result = result.substring(result.indexOf('\n') + 1);
       MessageBox.alert("Information","Result after substring: '" + result + "'");
       String returns = getReturns();
       MessageBox.alert("Information","Returns: '" + returns + "'");
       String action = getAction();
       MessageBox.alert("Information","Action: '" + action + "'");
       String finalResult = result + returns + action;
       MessageBox.alert("Information","Final result: '" + finalResult + "'");
}
```

Now the situation here is that, all of these : **getReturns()**, result and **getAction()** return non blank values, and in fact the string **finalResult** contains the concatenated value after the last line is executed. 
So, at Line 1, **"result"** contains *"12/03/2013|04-AERTY|"*. The value of result remains same at end of line 1,2. **getReturns()** returns value *12.4724*. So at end of line 3, **finalResult** contains *"12/03/2013|04-AERTY|12.4724"*. **getAction()** returns *"expt"*. So, at end of line 5, **finalResult** contains *"12/03/2013|04-AERTY|12.4724|expt"*

This is , when I debug or run the application in eclipse. As soon as build the same application on a UNIX system to generate a "war" file, and deploy the war on a tomcat server, the problem rears it's ugly head. When I run the application on the deployed war, the last line does not contain the concatenated value. So at the end of line 5, **finalResult** contains just *"12/03/2013|04-AERTY|12.4724"*. I expected it to contain *"12/03/2013|04-AERTY|12.4724|expt"* as it does while running in eclipse.

I have tried **stringbuffer**, **stringbuilder** and the **"+"** operator as well, but nothing seems to work. I am not even getting an exception.
Can somebody help me in fixing this or at least enlightening me in what I might be doing wrong here?

Just to stress again, the code on eclipse(which is on a windows machine) and UNIX machine are exactly same. I have done a diff on them.

Here is what I get after putting the message-boxes:

- Message-box 1:  "Result after trimming: '12/03/2013|04-AERTY|'"
- Message-box 2:   "Result after substring: '12/03/2013|04-AERTY|'"
- Message-box 3:"Returns: '12.4724'"
- Message-box 4:"Action: '|expt'"
- Message-box 5:"Final result: '12/03/2013|04-AERTY|12.4724|expt'"

Message-box 5 output is the one I receive when I execute code using eclipse
When running on deployed war, Message-box 1-4 have the same output as above, but Message-box 5 says: "Final result: '12/03/2013|04-AERTY|12.4724"

Comment: It would *really* help if you'd format your code sensibly. The indentation makes it very hard to read. I'll fix it for now, but please think about it when you post next time.

Comment: So, did you try remote debugging it? It sounds like either a line ending issue or the compiler optimizing away the last operation.

Comment: Wild guess: there is an extra 0 character at the end of the output of the `.getReturns()` function on Unix. What is this function's code?

Comment: @fge: Good point - I've adjusted the logging in my answer to help detect that.

Comment: Now could you include the output of the messageboxes in the failing situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear where the extra "|" is meant to come from - if `getAction()` just returns `expt`, the result would be `12/03/2013|04-AERTY|12.4724|expt`.

Anyway, I think it's safe to say that string concatenation will be working fine, and something else is wrong. You should add more diagnostics, logging everything:

```
public void handleSuccess(String result) {
    result = result.trim();
    log.info("Result after trimming: '" + result + "'");

    result = result.substring(result.indexOf('\n') + 1);
    log.info("Result after substring: '" + result + "'");

    String returns = getReturns();
    log.info("Returns: '" + returns + "'");

    String action = getAction();
    log.info("Action: '" + action + "'");

    // It's not clear what this is meant to do. I suggest you remove it and
    // use logging instead.
    MessageBox.alert("Information", "The selected action is " + action, null);             

    String finalResult = result + returns + action;
    log.info("Final result: '" + finalResult + "'");
```

I *suspect* you'll find that `action` is an empty string in the broken case.

Note that I've added quotes round each of the logged values, very deliberately. That means that if there's some unprintable character at the end of a string which causes problems, you should be able to detect that in the logging.

EDIT: As per the comment thread, when these were turned into message boxes (as it turns out this is running in GWT) it looks like there's something wrong with the early strings, as the closing `'` isn't seen in diagnostics, in the broken case. The OP is going to investigate further.

Comment: No sir, action is not empty. Like I said, the same code is working fine when I execute it on eclipse. The values received are same in both cases except for at the end of line 5. I have had many SOPs ad Message-Boxes, but have not posted them here for sake of brevity.

Comment: @user1314305: You *say* that `action` is not empty - and I'm sure it is when you're debugging in Eclipse, but I suspect it's not in the failure case. What do you think is more likely: that you've not quite diagnosed this properly, or that something so fundamental as string concatenation is broken? Just try adding the logging I've shown here - what have you got to lose?

Comment: I think when you call getAction() it's read corect value first time and you see correct value in MessageBox. But when you read second time for concat it return empty string for example.

Comment: @Jon, I tried using Log.info, but it does not write anything in the logs. May be I am looking at the wrong location, but the statements I used in other files using Logger.debug were present in the log, but the statements using log.info were not present at all. Now an obvious question would be, why did then I not use Logger.debug in this file too. Well, the answer is when I tried to do so, compiler gives me error ""no source code is available for type org.slf4j.Logger;
 did you forget to inherit a required module" -

Comment: Googling it reveals that this error is because I am trying to use this on a client side code with GWT. I am new to Java and all stuff , so unable to find a solution for this. Hence I resorted back to MessageBoxes for this. And the values are coming all right (except for Line 5). and getAction is not blank.  I am not alleging that concat is broken, I am saying there is something wrong the way I did things, but I am unable to find out. The values coming for each variable are same when I run it on eclipse and when I deploy it as war. Except for line 5. Anyways, thanks for putting efforts in it.

Comment: @user1314305: It would have been nice if you'd mentioned GWT before - this is the first we've heard of it. It's very hard to help without knowing the context. Where is this code actually running then?

Comment: Sorry about not mentioning GWT before. But could GWT be the reason for the problem I am facing with concatenation? The code is running on a Tomcat server deployed at one of the systems at my workplace.

Comment: @user1314305: Well it completely changes how things are running - if this is part of a GWT page then it's probably *not* running on your Tomcat server... it's being converted into Javascript which is running on the client.

Comment: I do not know so much about GWT and other things, as I said I am just a novice. So, let's say the GWT code gets converted into JS, which is running on the server, But even so, how does it affect the concatenation thing?

Comment: @user1314305: No, it's running on the *client* - that's the purpose of GWT. But to be honest, if you're relatively new to Java, I would actually try to tackle simpler things to start with. You're in a fairly complex area at this point.

Comment: Now I am even more confused. Regardless of the place (server or client) where it is running, how does it impact the concatenation. I am actually trying to find out simple thing viz. why is the string not getting concatenated. I am not even worried about complex thing like GWT or where is the code running. I just want the string to get concatenated. The code which I am dealing with is not written by me. It is written by someone else, I am just trying to append a value to it which I am not able to do.

Comment: @user1314305: I don't know how it would affect concatenation, but it definitely affects how you handle diagnostics. I'd still recommend *something* like the code I've presents, even if it turns into message boxes.

Comment: @Jon Skeet. Thanks Jon, I have updated my question with the new diagnostic message-boxes and also added the output I get. Still no luck.

Comment: @user1314305: You're sure message boxes 1-4 have *exactly* the same output (including the trailing `'` - double-check this, it's important) in the failing case?

Comment: Great. Looks like you are suspecting something and in correct direction!!!. The message-boxes have exactly the same output for the eclipse run and the war run. BUT the trailing `'` is not present when I run the application on the deployed war. Cant understand why should that happen.

Comment: @user1314305: Not present on *which line*? It sounds like you've probably got a Unicode `\0` character at the end of one of the strings, but you need to work out which.

Comment: @Jon Skeet  the trailing `'` is not present in ANY of the lines except the one which says `Action: '|expt'`

Comment: @user1314305: Okay, in that case it sounds like both `result` and `returns` has stray data. You might want to print out the length of the string, to work out how many dodgy characters are there. Then look at where they're coming from.

Comment: @Jon Skeet   Both of these are coming from a socket read. Will need to analyze further on that. However, what still puzzles me is why does it work when I run it on eclipse. Anyways, many thanks for spending so much time and efforts on this. Really appreciate this. Is there anyway your comment can be chosen as the correct answer. If not I will choose your answer as the correct solution.

Comment: @user1314305: I've updated my answer with the problem. My guess is that on the local machine, the client/server communication is quick enough that by the time you read the data, it's all there - but in the remote case, you get it a chunk at a time. That suggests you're possibly ignoring the result of `InputStream.read` somewhere.

Comment: Listen kid..., you dont argue with Jon Skeet, it is blasphemy.

Comment: @Rosdi Kasim  No, I didn't and won't :-)   But may I know who exactly are you and how did you infer that ;-)

Comment: @RosdiKasim I didn't see any argument in the comments between them...not closer even...it's just a discussion...